# Rearrangement diverges then original series also diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Question**: if $\sum y_n$ is "any" rearrangement of series $\sum x_n$ ,  where $\sum x_n$ is series of positive terms. Then, if $\sum y_n$ diverges then original series $\sum x_n$ also diverges?

I think yes. Because series $\sum x_n$ is series of positive terms and hence if we rearranged its terms then sum does not changed.

Am i correct? Hiw to prove it? Please help

Comment: "sum does not changed."  What sum? you don't have a sum.  The series diverges.

Comment: @fleablood  sir,  So am i incorrect? Is there is any counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A series of nonnegative numbers converges iff the series converges absolutely. A series converges absolutely iff every rearrangement of that series converges to the same limit.

Since there is a rearrangement that does not converge, the original series cannot converge absolutely. But the terms are nonnegative, so the original series diverges.

Comment: Sir, Hence it diverge?

Comment: @Andrew Shedlock when a series is absolutely convergent , then re-arrangement of that series is convergent and sum remains unaltered.                          But how do you know that the converse part is also true? Is there any proof that you got ? Please explain.

Comment: Could you write out the converse you are confused about?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers and that either

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \max\{x_n, 0\} < \infty \qquad\text{or}\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \max\{-x_n, 0\} < \infty $$

holds. (This in particular prevents the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ from converging conditionally.) Then we can prove that any rearrangement $(y_n)_{n\geq1}$ of $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ satisfies

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n, $$

regradless of whether they converge or not. (Note that each of these sums always has a value in the extended real number line $[-\infty,\infty]=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, and then the equality holds in $[-\infty,\infty]$.)

It can be proved by focusing on OP's case (where $x_n$'s are non-negative). Indeed, assuming that $x_n \geq n$ and $\sigma:\mathbb{N}_1\to\mathbb{N}_1$ is a bijection so that $y_n=x_{\sigma(n)}$, then for each given $m \geq 1$ there exists $N$ such that $\{1,\dots,m\}\subseteq\{\sigma(1),\dots,\sigma(N)\}$. Then for any $n\geq N$, we have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m} x_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} y_{k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k. $$

Letting $n\to\infty$, this shows that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m} x_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} y_{k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k $$

for any $m \geq 1$, then letting $m \to \infty$ proves the desired equality.